# How to achieve mouse click-through on NSView with CALayer?

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, mouseevent, calayer, nswindow

I have a custom borderless NSWindow in the shape of a circle. To do this I use a custom NSView that draws a filled circle.

Mouse clicks on a transparent pixel *inside the window's content rect* go straight through the window to whatever application happens to be behind it. Clicks inside the filled circle are intercepted by my application. So far so good.

The problem is that with the following line the above behavior changes and all clicks inside the windows's content rect are intercepted, transparent pixel or not:

```
[circleView setWantsLayer:YES];
```

Is there a way to have clicks on transparent pixels of `CALayer` instances go *through* the window/view/layer to the application behind it?

It's essentially the exact same problem as described below (only that the solution doesn't work in all cases, because it doesn't support animations):

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/235281-clicking-through-nsview-with-calayers.html

Comment: Is circleView the window's content view or is it a subview of the content view?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure whether this works on layer backed views, but a possible solution is to override `- (NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint` on your circle view subclass and check whether `aPoint` lies inside the path of the circle. If it's outside the circle, returning `nil` from that method should cause the click to be passed through.

Comment: Tested it quickly, doesn't work unfortunately. Clicks are still passed to the window, even when hitTest returns nil.

Comment: As hinted at the end of [1], it seems to work however with the conditional [NSWindow setIgnoresMouseEvents:NO] trick, by making use of an always listening NSTrackingArea, that is part of the content view. [1] — http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/303697-handling-mouse-events-on-transparent-window-conditionally.html

Answer (score 0):

A CAShapeLayer with CGPath will works, or you can create a CAShapeLayer as a mask to the content layer.

Answer (score 0):

When you created a `CALayer` inside a `NSView` you can ask the Views backing layer for its **farthest descendant of the receiver in its layer hierarchy**.
CALayers in **QuartzCore** have also a `hitTest:` method.

Once you catch a layer for this point you could ask for a given `name` property of your `CALayer` or CALayer Subclass in case you have several CALayers and need to know which of them exactly was hit. 
*CALayers do not have a .tag property.*

```objectivec
-(NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)p {
    __kindof CALayer *catched = [self.layer hitTest:point];
    NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([catched class]);
    NSLog(@"x%0.1f y%0.1f class:%@ name:%@", p.x, p.y, className, catched.name);
    return [super hitTest:p];
}
```

beware: the result may be `null` if there is no layer found.

Comment: answered 10 years later because google brought me here.